# SVG FeImage referencing a document element not working in latest Chrome

Tags: svg, svg-filters

Use case: Filling an SVG path or shape with fill/gradient/pattern/image using filters FeImage and FeComposite in 'in' mode.

Example: To fill a source rect with pink colour using filters, fill another rect (placed inside defs) with pink color. Refer that rect using feImage and do 'in' mode feComposite of the feImage into the SourceGraphic which is the source rect. This is demonstrated in the fiddle below.

Problem: This implementation was working until recently when I upgraded Chrome to v93. Can confirm this implementation works in Safari and in Chrome v88.

What I've tried: My original HTML is a complex one so I've created a fiddle in its simplest form. I've tried different dimensions on <filter> and a whole bunch of different parameters on all the elements. The fiddle HTML is very straight forward so not a lot to try on it.

Observations: When I inspect the defs rect in dev tools, chrome highlights it to be in the correct position which is above the source rect overlapping. But it looks like the actual render happens at 0,0. If I move the rects slowly towards 0,0, the color starts appearing. To see this, change the x and y of both rects to 0 and 0 respectively.

[Here is a fiddle that shows the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/sisirhellosivi/nj9xmsfu/). Opening the same in Safari or older versions of Chrome works.

```
<html>
  <body style="background: black">
    <svg
      version="1.1"
      id="editor_srdXQldLJ3O0111"
      width="450"
      height="450"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      style="z-index: 1"
    >
      <defs>
        <rect
          x="195.64463806152344"
          y="31.770639419555664"
          width="184.6571807861328"
          height="185.97244262695312"
          id="fillrect"
          fill="pink"
        ></rect>
        <filter
          id="main-filter"
          x="0"
          y="0"
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"
        >
          <feImage href="#fillrect" result="fe-img"></feImage>
          <feComposite
            operator="in"
            in="fe-img"
            in2="SourceGraphic"
          ></feComposite>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <g filter="url(#main-filter)">
        <rect
          x="195.64463806152344"
          y="31.770639419555664"
          width="184.6571807861328"
          height="185.97244262695312"
        />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yup - this is a bug - primitive dimensioning seems to be broken too

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1252720

Comment: This has now been fixed in Chrome top of trunk - so thank you for identifying it

Comment: Yup everything working good now. Thanks @MichaelMullany